# Как вывести месяц в родительном падеже в momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как вывести дату в родительном падеже в momentjs? Например, не *сентябрь*, а *сентября*.

Comment: А падежные формы русского языка точно есть в momentjs? Если у вас есть его исходники, выполните в директории с ними `grep -rni -e 'сентября'`.

Answer (score 2):

При формате moment проверяет регуляркой наличие даты перед месяцем.
В случае ее наличия, выводит месяц в родительном падеже.
Регулярка такая:

```
/D[oD]?(\[[^\[\]]*\]|\s+)+MMMM?/
```